# Unexplained space between two div in bootstrap.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Am using bootstrap.min.css i get unexplained space between two Div[image: listed with box]

i used the following code to remove white space, But does't works`div + div {margin-top:0px;}`

how to remove white space

```
<section id="service" style="background-color:#009999;">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</section>
     <!-------------white space appear here------------>
<section id="contact" style="background-color:#009999;">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: you can't use `div + div` since they are inside different elements http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors

Comment: you may need to set up an (jsfiddle) example with your css code and complete html of the area giving you trouble. PS. hoping both sections don't have same `id` in your code

Comment: @greener i have different ID for both section tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.box {
padding: 50px 30px;
background: #fff;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
position: relative;
}
```

remove this line `border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;`